# How can I set the value of a parameter that is not passed by reference in an Action<string, int>?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic-programming

I have a list of `Action<object, object>` and I end up getting this back into an `Action<string, int>` at some point, or any other two types. It represents a dynamic referential mapping from one type to another. For various reasons, I cannot use `ref` or `Func<..>`.

Basically the issue is that inside the callback code for that `Action<string, int>` I need a way to set the value of the `int` that is passed in, say after I convert it from a string. Though since it is not `ref`, it's not obvious how to do it.

Does anyone happen to know if there is a way to rewrite the method dynamically or otherwise get at the value that is passed into it (up the stack perhaps) and set the `int` value... one step up the CLR call stack?

To head off anyone saying "Why not change your whole program" or "When would you ever need this?", I am simply experimenting with the idea of a new kind of object mapping library.

Comment: You wouldn't, if it is not `ref` you cannot change the callers value.  You could return the new value allowing the caller to change it, but the version of the int that each has is different and isolated unless a reference is passed.

Comment: Well actually, you can change the caller's value. You can rewrite the method at run-time to be passed by ref and whatnot, but that's not a very good solution and I am trying to come up with a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, I would very much like to know the root answer!

So far, my best approach is to create your own delegate, and wrap them in generic

```
delegate void MyAction<T,T1>(ref T a, T1 b);
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyAction<string, int> action = Foo;            
        var arr = new object[] { "", 5 };
        action.DynamicInvoke(arr);
    }

    private static void Foo(ref string a, int b)
    {
        a = b.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: So the issue with this is that the `Action<string, int>` can't change. If I wrap it in an `Action<string, ref int>` then it gets passed up one level but not two, which is where it needs to be if it's wrapped. If it's not wrapped, it just needs to get passed up one more level.

Comment: Yes, it's only a work-around and does not solve the root problem which is someway for you to hack-in the IL code.
PS: what do you mean by two levels?

Comment: I mean that when you call a method inside a method, you end up with a stack depth of two, so if the idea was to wrap one method inside the other and have the innermost exposing a `ref` parameter, then you would need to still take that `ref` parameter and pass it back up the stack and hack in the IL somehow, except now it would be two layers of the stack instead of one. Each nested method call or invocation will cause an increase in the stack "frame" depth (with no optimization). But yeah, using `ref` just right out isn't possible with this application unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with value types. They are always copied on the stack and in case of boxing (for every boxing that is encountered) they are moved to a new location in heap and a reference is passed back.

You can try and wrap your int into a reference type and take advantage of side effects (since this is exactly what you are trying to do. Or you can keep the int parameter and store the result on a closed variable. E.g.: `(string str, int i) => { myDictionary.Add(str, i); }`.

Comment: Value types are not always copied on the stack, so I have a hard time believing that it is impossible based on what you've written. But, I am looking into reflecting out the caller and callee CIL at run-time in order to do what I want and access that boxed reference by playing with the stack, somehow.

Comment: This isn't true.  If the parameter has the `ref` modifier then it isn't copied, it's just aliased.  The question becomes how do you add the `ref` modifier to the delegate.  *If* you add the constraint that it's no possible to modify the delegate to use a `ref` parameter, *then* this answer would be correct, and you would need to wrap the value type in a reference type.

Comment: True that, only when parameters are passed by reference values are not copied but referenced. But the Action delegates do not have any ref modifiers on any definition.

Elaborate "playing with the stack"